# Firebase Profile Photo Retreive via uid

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

i am Beginner please help me with this code..it shows nothing in image view...how can i get Profile image of the user currently login.

Here is my activity

```
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUsers;
    String post_key = null;
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    private TextView txt,url;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private ImageView img;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile2);

        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.userimg);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profile_images");
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        String name = sharedpreferences.getString("name", null);
        editor.commit();
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user);
        txt.setText(name);


        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // Name, email address, and profile photo Url

            Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();
            Glide.with(this).load(photoUrl).into(img);
            String uid = user.getUid();
            //Picasso.with(context).load(photoUrl).into(img);

        }
    }


}
```

Here is Xml

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:id="@+id/userimg"

            />
```

here is how my firebase look

```
Users
HzId4iQoBiZl4vcC2lcO7kHxFvx1
Username: 
"Humayun"
image: 
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-..."
name: 
"Being"
```

Here is log

```
08-07 23:53:02.980 990-990/com.example.ekene.blogzone D/ViewRootImpl@23bca1a[SettingsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
08-07 23:53:03.032 990-990/com.example.ekene.blogzone D/ViewRootImpl@23bca1a[SettingsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
08-07 23:53:03.053 990-1029/com.example.ekene.blogzone V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 7132
08-07 23:53:03.054 990-1029/com.example.ekene.blogzone V/FA: Connecting to remote service
08-07 23:53:03.059 990-1029/com.example.ekene.blogzone V/FA: Activity paused, time: 85858553
08-07 23:53:03.061 990-1029/com.example.ekene.blogzone D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=7132, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SettingsActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=779955923523228885}]
08-07 23:53:03.074 990-990/com.example.ekene.blogzone V/FA: onActivityCreated
08-07 23:53:03.074 990-1029/com.example.ekene.blogzone V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
08-07 23:53:03.222 990-1029/com.example.ekene.blogzone V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
08-07 23:53:03.223 990-1029/com.example.ekene.blogzone V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 85858723
08-07 23:53:03.226 990-1029/com.example.ekene.blogzone D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=SettingsActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=779955923523228885, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Profile, firebase_screen_id(_si)=779955923523228886}]
08-07 23:53:03.230 990-990/com.example.ekene.blogzone D/ViewRootImpl@799292b[Profile]: setView = DecorView@a88d746[Profile] TM=true MM=false
08-07 23:53:03.231 990-990/com.example.ekene.blogzone D/ViewRootImpl@23bca1a[SettingsActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
08-07 23:53:03.237 990-1029/com.example.ekene.blogzone V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
08-07 23:53:03.241 990-990/com.example.ekene.blogzone D/ViewRootImpl@799292b[Profile]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
08-07 23:53:03.253 990-990/com.example.ekene.blogzone V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
08-07 23:53:03.254 990-990/com.example.ekene.blogzone D/ViewRootImpl@799292b[Profile]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 503392329728} changed=true
08-07 23:53:03.265 990-1103/com.example.ekene.blogzone D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1440x2960]-format:1
08-07 23:53:03.265 990-1103/com.example.ekene.blogzone D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x755a21ee00
08-07 23:53:03.270 990-1029/com.example.ekene.blogzone D/FA: Connected to remote service
08-07 23:53:03.270 990-1029/com.example.ekene.blogzone V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
08-07 23:53:03.273 990-990/com.example.ekene.blogzone D/ViewRootImpl@799292b[Profile]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2960) ci=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 168) vi=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 168) or=1
    MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
08-07 23:53:03.275 990-990/com.example.ekene.blogzone V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@509c45d nm : com.example.ekene.blogzone ic=null
08-07 23:53:03.275 990-990/com.example.ekene.blogzone I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
08-07 23:53:03.341 990-1103/com.example.ekene.blogzone D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x751db50540
08-07 23:53:03.352 990-990/com.example.ekene.blogzone D/ViewRootImpl@23bca1a[SettingsActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1440,2960] new=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true
```

i am Beginner please help me with this code..it shows nothing in image view...how can i get Profile image of the user currently login.

Comment: What is the value of `photoUrl`?

Comment: It should be user profile image url when he registered....like this "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-..."..
I check it in text view too but it shows nothing there too

Comment: I'm asking what is the actual value at runtime, not what it should be.  If there is no actual value (it's null), then obviously you won't have a picture to display.  You're not accessing the database to show the picture, you're asking Firebase Authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your database structure

> `Users
>   HzId4iQoBiZl4vcC2lcO7kHxFvx1
>   Username: 
>   "Humayun"
>   image: 
>   "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-..."
>   name: 
>   "Being"`

You will need to construct a link to access the image url. 
Use this code

```
database.child(user.getUID()).child(user.getDisplayName()).child("image")
.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
       //inside the ondatachange, get the url
       //snapshot.getValue().toString() then you can set the image
    });
```

Comment: @Humayun Please upvote and accept it as the correct answer then

Answer (score 0):

If you are using email/password for authentication. it doesn't contain profileImage by default. You have to update your profile image (also another property) by

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setDisplayName("Humayun")
        .setPhotoUri("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-...")
        .build();

user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
                }
            }
        });
```

and then you will be able to get your profile image through user like you did before

```
Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();
Glide.with(this).load(photoUrl).into(img);
```

Comment: Profile image is there when user registered with name and picture...u can see firebase it shows the url like &quot;https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-...&quot; this is user profile image name  Humayun

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me..

```
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).child(user.getDisplayName()).child("image")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        String image=dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                        Picasso.with(Profile.this).load(image).into(img);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }

                });
```